# Average power across a resistor

Tags: power, rms

I am solving a problem here that asks for average power across a resistor.... the resistor is 3k and V(s) = 1.897sin(500t - 71.6)...

I found 0.8 mW ....but the answer book says that it is 0.6mW ...

isnt it ... (Vrms)^2 over 3k ?
Vrms = 1.897/sqrt(2)?

***if A = 1.987 ... the power comes out to be 0.6mW ....I do not know if I am right or the booklet is [image]

Comment: congratulations, with 32 `.`, it's your favourite new character. Sadly, "..." doesn't contain any information.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just a arithmetic mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct - maybe just a calculating mistake?

Pave = VRMS^2/R, and VRMS=1.897/sqrt(2)

> > (1.897/sqrt(2))^2/3000

ans =

5.9977e-04